# Error in UnsafeMutablePointer in swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

My codd look like this

```
let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start:UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData), count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))
```

While running this code is generating the following error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'
```

buffer.mdata is having raw data. How can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit question to show the `mData` declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `buffer` is a `AudioBuffer` from the `AVFoundation`
framework: `buffer.mData` is a "optional raw pointer" 
`UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`, and in Swift 3 you have to *bind*
the raw pointer to a typed pointer:

```
let buffer: AudioBuffer = ...

if let mData = buffer.mData {
    let numSamples = Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
    let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: mData.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: numSamples),
                                             count: numSamples)
    // ...
}
```

See [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)
for more information about raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

```
// Creates an UnsafeMutablePointer over the count contiguous Element instances beginning at start.
init(start: UnsafeMutablePointer<Element>?, count: Int)
```

So

```
let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start:UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData), count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))
```

will be like:

```
let byteSize = Int16(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeOf(Int16)
let buffer:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16> = buffer.mData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self)
let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start:buffer, count:byteSize)
```

There are different ways to convert `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`.
One conversion is already given by Martin in above answer, and other is in this example.